# Bootstrap input tags display alert message when reached maxTags

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-tags-input

I'm using [bootstrap tags input](https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/) and below code is working fine. I'm using `maxTags: 10` so a user can select maximum 10 languages and if they try to add more then it don't appear in the input field.

My question is to display an alert message when a user try to select more than `maxTags`. I checked their documentation and couldn't get any solution. Is it possible to do with bootstrap tags input? or any other solution to display an alert if user reached maxTags.

Please help...

```
var languages = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace("name")
    , queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace
    , prefetch: "./assets/languages.json"
});
languages.initialize(), 
$("#inputtags").tagsinput({
    maxTags: 10
    , freeInput: !1
    , typeaheadjs: {
        name: "id"
        , displayKey: "name"
        , valueKey: "name"
        , source: languages.ttAdapter()
    }
});
```

Comment: I would simply put your maxTags in a variable and write a simple if statement that when maxTags > 10 raises an alert with some text like 'maximum amount of languages selected'.

Comment: @mrdeadsven how you will create a variable inside `tagsinput` function. I tried its showing error.

Comment: Not in taginput, I would create a variable teller and set it to 0. Everytime they select a language I would do teller = teller + 1 and when teller > 10 show the alert.

Comment: Yeah, I understand it. I will try my best to fix this issue. But the hard part is how to identify that user select values. If its button `clicks` or `onchange` we can do something. But in this plugin, it keeps adding a span to each value. Also, this is not only adding values. In edit profile, it will display already selected values and the user can add more values maximum is 10. So little complex I feel.

Comment: Ye I'm not familiar with the plugin sorry. But if it keeps adding spans you could create your variable on these. Simply add one to the variable for each span on your page?

Comment: Sorry had to look up the code again... 'document.getElementsByTagName("span").length' this should give you a count of all the spans in your page hope this helps.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167738/discussion-between-acmsohail-and-mrdeadsven).

Comment: yeah I already tried that `var numItems = $('.tag').length;console.log(numItems);` its showing the values. but the issue is, when a user enters more than 10 languages then the span is not adding in the frontend. So the alert function doesn't work. If it's added to frontend then only it will check and display the alert.

Comment: use = 10 instead of > 10? and make the alert a warning like 'warning you can no longer add languages because you have reached a maximum of 10'?

Comment: @mrdeadsven thanks for the suggestion. I updated the answer please check it :)

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution by taking the `length` of the `span` class and validate it. When a user clicks input tag then it will calculate the length of selected span and validate it. Currently, it's working fine without any error. If you find any other best solution please suggest.

Thanks to @mrdeadsven

```
$(".tt-dataset-id").click(function(){ 
    var numItems = $('.tag').length -1; //when page load it has one extra span for .tag class
    console.log(numItems);
    if(numItems>=10){
        alert('Maximum 10 languages are allowed');
    }
});
```